# Names of bigq vectors (R package gmp)

Tags: r, gmp

The `names` function for `bigq` vectors of the `gmp` R package does not work as one could expect:

```
> library(gmp)
> x <- as.bigq(c(0.5,0.5))
> names(x) <- c("a", "b")
> names(x)
 [1] "a" "b" NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Thus I define a `names` function for the `bigq` class as follows, and it works fine:

```
> names.bigq <- function(x) attr(x, "names")[1:length(x)]
> names(x)
[1] "a" "b"
```

Even `names(x) <-` and `setNames` work fine with the `names.bigq` function. But the access to an element of a vector by its name does not work:

```
> x["a"]
bigq(0)
```

Is there a way to make it work ? If `x["a"]` were the same as `x[which(names(x)=="a")]` then it would be fine:

```
> x[which(names(x)=="a")]
Big Rational ('bigq') :
[1] 1/2
```

**Note:** A possible workaround consists in converting and back-converting `x` in character mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function extracting an element in a `bigq` vector or matrix by its index is the internal `` `[.bigq` `` function:

```
> gmp:::`[.bigq`
function (x, i = NULL, j = NULL, drop = TRUE) 
{
    .Call(matrix_get_at_q, x, i, j)
}
<environment: namespace:gmp>
```

Then overwrite it by this one:

```
`[.bigq` <- function (x, i = NULL, j = NULL, drop = TRUE) 
{
  if(is.character(i)){ i <- which(names(x)==i) }
  .Call(gmp:::matrix_get_at_q, x, i, j)
}
```

And it works:

```
> x <- as.bigq(c(2,5))
> names(x) <- c("a", "b")
> x[1]
Big Rational ('bigq') :
[1] 2
> x["a"]
Big Rational ('bigq') :
[1] 2
```

***Better:***

```
`[.bigq` <- function (x, i = NULL, j = NULL, drop = TRUE) 
{
  if(is.character(i)){ i <- sapply(i, function(k) which(names(x)==k), USE.NAMES=FALSE) }
  .Call(gmp:::matrix_get_at_q, x, i, j)
}
```

to get:

```
> x[c("a","b")]
Big Rational ('bigq') object of length 2:
[1] 1 2
> x[c("b","a")]
Big Rational ('bigq') object of length 2:
[1] 2 1
```